# Origen del solotildismo ~ sobre la tilde en sólo, éste, ése y aquél

Tags: historia, acentuación

Hace poco me enteré de que la manía de tildar *sólo*, para diferenciarla del otro *solo*, había sido desaconsejada hace ya una década; siendo que hay sólo dos *solos* y en donde si sólo se acepta uno de ellos sus significados se confundirán como si fuesen uno solo. Si esto no bastó [Reverte lo hizo mejor](https://twitter.com/perezreverte/status/1271856108206989313); a tal punto que la RAE, quien parece tener problemas para satisfacer las demandas de sus clientes, [debió levantar dicha proscripción](https://www.lagaceta.com.ar/nota/984312/sociedad/victoria-solotildistas-confirma-maravilla-lengua.html) este mismo año.

Ahora sí, vamos al grano. ¿Quién inventó esta (sagrada) costumbre de tildar *s**ó**lo* para diferenciar su uso y resolver las ambigüedades que pudieren surgir, eximiendo la palabra de las reglas de acentuación? ¿Sucedió antes o después de que se ‘inventaran’ las reglas de acentuación? ¿Cuáles son los registros más antiguos del empleo de la tilde en dicha palabra? ¿Sucedió a la par de *éste*, *ése*, *aquél* y todas sus variantes?

Comment: El sistema de SE es pregunta=respuesta y esta debe ser útil para cualquier usuario. Estás realizando **tres preguntas**, todas muy amplias de criterio, no creo que sean fácilmente respondidas. De hecho, quien se anime a responder debería escribir un compendio.

Comment: Las tres preguntas son la misma "¿Cuál es el origen de la costumbre de usar tilde diacrítica en *solo*?" No creo que merezca la pena ser exigente con el número de signos de interrogación que aparecen en el texto: a mí la pregunta me parece bastante concreta.

Comment: En realidad, la recomendación data de 1960, nada menos. En 2010 se proscribió el uso de la tilde, aconsejando utilizar otras construcciones si quien escribe cree que puede haber ambigüedad (es muy fácil escribir *solamente* en lugar de *solo*). Y ahora la Academia se ha hartado de quejas y ha vuelto a la recomendación de 1960: no tildar salvo en casos de posible ambigüedad. Lo que lleva a que esos *solotildistas* pongan la tilde siempre, qué le vamos a hacer.

Answer (score 2):

De acuerdo, ya que nadie se animó a responder voy a hacerlo yo mismo con toda la información que recogí. Me encontré con algunas sorpresas.

En primer lugar, soy consciente de que el lenguaje surge del uso que le dan los hablantes. Las formalizaciones de la RAE en ‘reglas’ son posteriores a esto y nunca ocurre al revés. Pero lo que no imaginaba es que esto aplicaba también para las reglas de acentuación.

El debate acerca de si es indispensable el uso de las tildes y sobre cuál es la forma maś adecuada de llevarlo a cabo ha existido prácticamente desde que los españoles tuvieron conciencia de que ya no hablaban latín—recordemos que en latín no habían tildes. Por ejemplo, Juan de Valdés en el *Diálogo de la lengua* (1533):

> M. ¿Y querriades que todos usassen este señalar de acentos en el escrivir?
> V. Si querria, [...] porque a poca costa les enseñarian como an de leer lo que les escriven.

El primer intento de formalización de las reglas de acentuación por parte de la RAE lo encontramos en la *[Orthographía española](https://www.rae.es/sites/default/files/Ortografia_RAE_1741_reducida.pdf)* de 1741. Eran conscientes de que el acento gráfico debía existir en la menor cantidad de palabras posibles y por lo tanto en los casos menos frecuentes. Las palabras agudas se acentuaban sólo cuando terminaban en *-a*, *-e*, *-o*, *-s* y *-n* (esta última sólo en verbos); en las llanas funcionaba a la inversa. Las esdrújulas se acentuaban siempre.

En la *[Ortografía](https://ia800300.us.archive.org/19/items/ortografadelale01espagoog/ortografadelale01espagoog.pdf)* de 1820 ya se evidencia un cambio en las reglas generales. Ahora la tilde debe ir en palabras agudas que terminen en vocal o *-n* (sólo en verbos), o bien las palabras graves que no cumplan la condición anterior. Las esdrújulas no varían.

Y llegamos al *[Prontuario](https://books.google.es/books?vid=BNC1001910344&printsec=frontcover&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false)* de 1854. Las reglas generales cambian otra vez, ahora la tilde debe ir únicamente en palabras agudas que terminen en vocal, en llanas que terminen en consonante y en las esdrújulas. En los casos de las palabras con varias acentuaciones posibles recomiendan tildar siempre para evitar la ambigüedad. Y lo más importante:

> *Solo*, como adverbio, deberá acentuarse cuando, de no hacerlo, se pueda confundir con el adjetivo, v. gr. Voy sólo (solamente) por complacer á usted; voy solo (sin compañía) porque así me conviene.

> *Este* y *aquel* puede necesitar acento en alguna ocasion, v. gr. Llegaron á Madrid el Conde y el Duque, declarado éste competidor con el otro. Era llamado aquél hombre justo por excelencia.

Adicionalmente, se legisló el uso de la tilde en *aun*, *para*, *entre*, *sobre* y *luego* para distinguir entre sus posibles acepciones cuando hubiera ambigüedad.

En el [Pronturario](https://ia801409.us.archive.org/1/items/prontuariodeorto00real/prontuariodeorto00real.pdf) de 1909 ya podemos ver las reglas generales de acentuación tal como las conocemos hoy en día. Sin embargo, tengo sospechas de que estas se consolidaron en los Prontuarios que salieron entre 1870 y 1880.

Por lo tanto, el primer registro que hallé en el que la RAE reconozca a *sólo* es en 1854, pero en [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=s%C3%B3lo&year_start=1700&year_end=2019&corpus=es-2019&smoothing=3) hay pruebas de que esta práctica existía antes de 1800. Lo mismo vale para *éste*, *ése* y *aquél*.

El resto es historia conocida. Según tengo entendido, en alguno de los congresos que se llevó a cabo en la década de 1950 se impuso como obligatorio el solotildismo. Después, en 1999 se dejó su uso como facultativo. En 2010 la RAE lo proscribió y finalmente en el presente año debe dar marcha atrás.

**Conclusiones**: Los usos del acento gráfico en castellano surgieron de la propia conciencia de los hablantes para resolver las ambigüedades que puedan darse en la lectura de los textos. En este sentido, el uso de la tilde en sólo ya existía antes de la primera formalización de las reglas de acentuación, pero es difícil encontrar una prueba sólida con el primer texto en el que se atestigüe su uso.

Les recomiendo este [artículo](https://revistas.rae.es/brae/article/view/159) en donde se documentan fechas en las que se legisló el uso de la tilde en *sólo* y en otras palabras que escapan a las reglas generales de acentuación (como algunos monosílabos y pronombres). En el mismo también se reconoce que en el Prontuario de 1870 se legisló a favor del solotildismo debido a que era una vieja costumbre. Y, aunque la postura de quien lo escribió es claramente en contra, ojalá que este hábito nunca cese.